# Remove device from ubuntu one through API

Tags: ubuntu-one, logout, ubuntu-one-api

How to create API Request to remove a device from ubuntu one?I need to delete current access token from server through API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to make an OAuth signed request to the following URL:

`https://one.ubuntu.com/api/1.0/devices/remove/computer/${device_id}`

where `${device_id}` is the device ID of the device in question, which seems to be:

`Computer${token}`

where `${token}` is the token of the device being removed.